# How I can convert Basic Multilingual Plane (escaped string \uXXXX) to UTF-8 in PHP 5.3.x?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, escaping

I really prefer avoid those regular expression that exist out there cos tons of them don't work in all cases and I don't want analyze after read the standard if a reg exp is correct or not. What I'm finding is something native.

Comment: Do you really need to convert them? If you use those in JavaScript or `json_decode`, everything will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MarcelKorpel, but I'm working on a client side of an API with PHP 5.3.x, not have other choice :(

Comment: Yes, but with `json_decode` those escaped strings will be converted to UTF-8 chars, like `json_decode('"foo\u013abar!"') == 'fooĺbar!'`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel you are right, I just read wrongly your comment. Thanks! If you reply I will pick your reply ;) Thanks again and sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert those characters to UTF-8. Like:

```
$json = '"foo\u013abar!"';
$info = json_decode($json);
echo $info;  // outputs fooĺbar!
```

Be sure to feed `json_decode` well-formed [JSON](http://json.org).